# Rancher server behind Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, rancher

I have a Nginx on host, a Rancher server in `Docker` container. I want to use `Nginx` reverse proxy Rancher:

Here is my Nginx config:

```
 map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default Upgrade;
        ''      close;
    }

    location /rancher {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    }
```

But when I try to access `https://mydomain/rancher` , static files can not be loaded. I want to know:

- Does it common to run Rancher server behind a `Nginx` proxy?
- How can I make my config work?

Comment: is this inside your mydomain server block?

Comment: @Skyler yes, this config block is inside `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` in host, not in another docker container.

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing you want to access your application over TLS. Try the following configuration,

```
server {
  listen 443 default_server;
  server_name mydomain;
  ssl_certificate     www.example.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;
  ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

  location /rancher {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
  }

}
```

Comment: exactly, I want to running rancher behind Nginx which setup TLS, actually I did not find any difference between your config block and mine. I pasted your config block into my Nginx config file, static files still can not loaded(404).